# Is a photo of Rick Perry's college transcript authentic?

Tags: united-states, politics

Various major US news outlets are echoing a [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/08/05/rick-perry-college-transcript_n_919357.html) article titled "Rick Perry's College Transcript: A Lot Of Cs And Ds" including [NPR](http://www.npr.org/blogs/itsallpolitics/2011/08/05/139027418/rick-perrys-college-transcript-a-warning-to-all-future-politicians), [Fox](http://nation.foxnews.com/rick-perry/2011/08/05/left-leaks-perrys-college-transcript-still-waiting-obamas), and the [Des Moines Register](http://caucuses.desmoinesregister.com/2011/08/05/college-transcripts-for-texas-rick-perry-reveal-some-poor-grades/).

> Because if you ever enter politics, you may one day think about running for president. And if you do decide to run, your college grades could become an issue, especially if they're mediocre.
>
> That's what Texas Gov. Rick Perry is learning the hard way, now that what's reportedly his college transcript is on the Internet for the eyes of Texas and the world to gaze upon, courtesy of the Huffington Post.
>
> He was well acquainted with Bs, Cs and Ds. A pre-veterinary student, he got an F in organic chemistry. While many people won't hold that against him, it may help explain why he's not a practicing veterinarian today.

Perry (a former candidate in the U.S. Republican presidential primary) seems to have neither confirmed nor denied the transcript's accuracy.

> The governor’s office did not return a request for comment from The Huffington Post.

How do journalists test the provenance of leaked documents like this?

Comment: Who is rick perry?

Comment: Two words:  Dan Rather

Comment: Sklivvz - I updated the question so it was more clear that this was about US politics.

Comment: @Russel, thanks.  I had hoped that "major US news outlets" had made that clear, but I guess people often skip to the bottom where the question-mark appears.

Comment: The more interesting question is whether - should it be a real transcript - the Obama Justice Dept would zealously pursue whoever committed a crime by violating what are probably a bunch of privacy laws by leaking it.

Comment: @Mike -- It's shocking but "major US news outlets" do sometimes report on political news from other countries.  Odd, but true.

Comment: I don't know if the picture is, but Rick Perry is not authentic.

Comment: See also:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/what-does-ive-got-my-fist-cocked-if-you-still-want-to-f-with-me-mean-in-re (_What does “I’ve got my fist cocked if you still want to f*** with me,” mean in reference to the comment on the hard-boiled character of Rick Perry?_)

Comment: @Moab:  They still call themselves journalists, so, naturally, their audience continues to make the same error.

Comment: Voted to close. This is not a question covered by the rules, fixed in the faq. It invites speculation and does not challenge a notable claim (how the press works?).

Comment: @russell well, maybe if he'd convened an entire stadium full of people to pray for better grades...

Comment: @Monkey - if that worked, wouldn't Boston Red Sox win more games?

Comment: I see one of my comments was deleted, thanks.

Comment: He graduated from Texas A&M so a sure way to check is to see if it was written in crayon. (We Longhorns can't pass up an opportunity to dig on Aggies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is authentic.

[Perry acknowledged that his transcript has been published](http://thehill.com/video/campaign/189945-perry-has-no-doubt-obamas-an-american-citizen-wants-transcripts):

> Let's lay out our income taxes. Let's lay our college transcripts. *Mine's been on the front page of the paper*.

Comment: +1 way to fix a bit of a broken window by having no answer here for so long!